# How do i rename key names in a json and recreate it?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have the following `json` array (the original data comes from ASP MVC as XML but i have converted them to json)

```
{"class":{"@Title":"SOCIAL HISTORY","@ID":"1","@ParentID":"0","helpNavNode":[{"@Title":"ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION","@ID":"2","@ParentID":"1","helpNavNode":[{"@Title":" Never","@ID":"3","@ParentID":"2","@Narrative":"ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Never"},{"@Title":" Occasionally","@ID":"4","@ParentID":"2","@Narrative":"ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Occasionally"},{"@Title":" Socially","@ID":"5","@ParentID":"2","@Narrative":"ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Socially"},{"@Title":" Daily (3 beers/day) (6 pack/day)","@ID":"6","@ParentID":"2","@Narrative":"ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Daily (3 beers/day) (6 pack/day)"},{"@Title":" Is Alcoholic","@ID":"7","@ParentID":"2","@Narrative":"ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Is Alcoholic"},{"@Title":" History of Alcoholism","@ID":"8","@ParentID":"2","@Narrative":"ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: History of Alcoholism"},{"@Title":" None","@ID":"26","@ParentID":"2","@Narrative":"ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: None"},{"@Title":"Alcoholism Screen Question","@ID":"39","@ParentID":"2","helpNavNode":{"@Title":" Ever had a drinking problem? Last drink? ","@ID":"40","@ParentID":"39","@Narrative":"ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION:Alcoholism Screen Question: Ever had a drinking problem? Last drink? "}}]},{"@Title":"MARITAL STATUS","@ID":"9","@ParentID":"1","helpNavNode":[{"@Title":" Married","@ID":"10","@ParentID":"9","helpNavNode":{"@Title":" x 10 years","@ID":"15","@ParentID":"10","@Narrative":"MARITAL STATUS: Married: x 10 years"}},{"@Title":" Divorced","@ID":"11","@ParentID":"9","@Narrative":"MARITAL STATUS: Divorced"},{"@Title":" Single","@ID":"12","@ParentID":"9","@Narrative":"MARITAL STATUS: Single"}]},{"@Title":"Recreational drug use","@ID":"13","@ParentID":"1","@Narrative":":Recreational drug use"},{"@Title":"OCCUPATION","@ID":"14","@ParentID":"1","helpNavNode":{"@Title":" works for  x 27 years","@ID":"25","@ParentID":"14","@Narrative":"OCCUPATION: works for  x 27 years"}},{"@Title":" 1 child","@ID":"16","@ParentID":"1","@Narrative":": 1 child"},{"@Title":" 2/3/4/5/6 children","@ID":"17","@ParentID":"1","@Narrative":": 2/3/4/5/6 children"},{"@Title":"Activities","@ID":"18","@ParentID":"1","helpNavNode":[{"@Title":" walks regularly","@ID":"19","@ParentID":"18","@Narrative":"Activities: walks regularly"},{"@Title":" cycles for exercise","@ID":"20","@ParentID":"18","@Narrative":"Activities: cycles for exercise"},{"@Title":" runs 3 days/week","@ID":"21","@ParentID":"18","@Narrative":"Activities: runs 3 days/week"},{"@Title":" hunting and fishing","@ID":"22","@ParentID":"18","@Narrative":"Activities: hunting and fishing"},{"@Title":" hiking and camping","@ID":"23","@ParentID":"18","@Narrative":"Activities: hiking and camping"},{"@Title":" swims regularly","@ID":"24","@ParentID":"18","@Narrative":"Activities: swims regularly"}]},{"@Title":"Tobacco Use","@ID":"27","@ParentID":"1","helpNavNode":[{"@Title":"Cigar, Cigarette, Pipe, Smokeless","@ID":"30","@ParentID":"27","helpNavNode":{"@Title":"10/pk year","@ID":"32","@ParentID":"30","@Narrative":"Tobacco Use:Cigar, Cigarette, Pipe, Smokeless:10/pk year"}},{"@Title":"Quit Date","@ID":"35","@ParentID":"27","@Narrative":"Tobacco Use:Quit Date"},{"@Title":"Year Started","@ID":"36","@ParentID":"27","@Narrative":"Tobacco Use:Year Started"}]},{"@Title":"SocHx  Template","@ID":"37","@ParentID":"1","helpNavNode":[{"@Title":" Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: ","@ID":"41","@ParentID":"37","@Narrative":"SocHx  Template: Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: "},{"@Title":" Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: ","@ID":"42","@ParentID":"37","@Narrative":"SocHx  Template: Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: "}]}]}}
```

two things i want to do with this:

1. i want to remove the `@` symbol from where ever it appears
2. i need to change the key names into the following:

@Title => text

@ID => id

@ParentID => parent

@Narrative => value

Is there away i could accomplish this? at the moment i wouldn't have a clue on how do it them?

UPDATE:

how `json` was created. the `XMLDocument` comes from `BLL` classes and the following is placed on client the hard coded XML file has a copy of what is returned from BLL so its easy to check it in the client (from my perspective)

```
@{
 var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load(Server.MapPath(Url.Content(@"~/App_Data/XMLFile1.xml")));
    var jsonObj=JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xdoc);
}
```

Comment: Then you should be creating a collection of anonymous objects in your controller method based your data. How are you currently creating that json?

Comment: @StephenMuecke i thought that too but the BLL classes sends data as XML and in the client i convert it to json. It would be alot easier to send data from BLL as json but at the moment i cannot change BLL methods or add them : (

Comment: In you controller method your should be converting the XML your getting to a model, and then to change the names, you map the model to an anonymous object and then return that as json to the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have updated my OP

Comment: OMG. That code should not be in a view!

Comment: @StephenMuecke its in the view!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103671/discussion-between-zeelong-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: wondering if the answer helped...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by stringifying the JSON and performing string manipulation as shown below:

```
var mapping = {
      '@Title': 'text',
      '@ID': 'id',
      '@ParentID': 'parent',
      '@Narrative': 'value'
}
var temp = JSON.stringify(data);
for (key in mapping) {
  temp = temp.replace(new RegExp(key, 'g'), mapping[key]);
}
data = JSON.parse(temp.replace(/@/g, ''));
```

```js
var data = {
  "class": {
    "@Title": "SOCIAL HISTORY",
    "@ID": "1",
    "@ParentID": "0",
    "helpNavNode": [{
      "@Title": "ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION",
      "@ID": "2",
      "@ParentID": "1",
      "helpNavNode": [{
        "@Title": " Never",
        "@ID": "3",
        "@ParentID": "2",
        "@Narrative": "ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Never"
      }, {
        "@Title": " Occasionally",
        "@ID": "4",
        "@ParentID": "2",
        "@Narrative": "ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Occasionally"
      }, {
        "@Title": " Socially",
        "@ID": "5",
        "@ParentID": "2",
        "@Narrative": "ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Socially"
      }, {
        "@Title": " Daily (3 beers/day) (6 pack/day)",
        "@ID": "6",
        "@ParentID": "2",
        "@Narrative": "ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Daily (3 beers/day) (6 pack/day)"
      }, {
        "@Title": " Is Alcoholic",
        "@ID": "7",
        "@ParentID": "2",
        "@Narrative": "ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Is Alcoholic"
      }, {
        "@Title": " History of Alcoholism",
        "@ID": "8",
        "@ParentID": "2",
        "@Narrative": "ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: History of Alcoholism"
      }, {
        "@Title": " None",
        "@ID": "26",
        "@ParentID": "2",
        "@Narrative": "ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: None"
      }, {
        "@Title": "Alcoholism Screen Question",
        "@ID": "39",
        "@ParentID": "2",
        "helpNavNode": {
          "@Title": " Ever had a drinking problem? Last drink? ",
          "@ID": "40",
          "@ParentID": "39",
          "@Narrative": "ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION:Alcoholism Screen Question: Ever had a drinking problem? Last drink? "
        }
      }]
    }, {
      "@Title": "MARITAL STATUS",
      "@ID": "9",
      "@ParentID": "1",
      "helpNavNode": [{
        "@Title": " Married",
        "@ID": "10",
        "@ParentID": "9",
        "helpNavNode": {
          "@Title": " x 10 years",
          "@ID": "15",
          "@ParentID": "10",
          "@Narrative": "MARITAL STATUS: Married: x 10 years"
        }
      }, {
        "@Title": " Divorced",
        "@ID": "11",
        "@ParentID": "9",
        "@Narrative": "MARITAL STATUS: Divorced"
      }, {
        "@Title": " Single",
        "@ID": "12",
        "@ParentID": "9",
        "@Narrative": "MARITAL STATUS: Single"
      }]
    }, {
      "@Title": "Recreational drug use",
      "@ID": "13",
      "@ParentID": "1",
      "@Narrative": ":Recreational drug use"
    }, {
      "@Title": "OCCUPATION",
      "@ID": "14",
      "@ParentID": "1",
      "helpNavNode": {
        "@Title": " works for  x 27 years",
        "@ID": "25",
        "@ParentID": "14",
        "@Narrative": "OCCUPATION: works for  x 27 years"
      }
    }, {
      "@Title": " 1 child",
      "@ID": "16",
      "@ParentID": "1",
      "@Narrative": ": 1 child"
    }, {
      "@Title": " 2/3/4/5/6 children",
      "@ID": "17",
      "@ParentID": "1",
      "@Narrative": ": 2/3/4/5/6 children"
    }, {
      "@Title": "Activities",
      "@ID": "18",
      "@ParentID": "1",
      "helpNavNode": [{
        "@Title": " walks regularly",
        "@ID": "19",
        "@ParentID": "18",
        "@Narrative": "Activities: walks regularly"
      }, {
        "@Title": " cycles for exercise",
        "@ID": "20",
        "@ParentID": "18",
        "@Narrative": "Activities: cycles for exercise"
      }, {
        "@Title": " runs 3 days/week",
        "@ID": "21",
        "@ParentID": "18",
        "@Narrative": "Activities: runs 3 days/week"
      }, {
        "@Title": " hunting and fishing",
        "@ID": "22",
        "@ParentID": "18",
        "@Narrative": "Activities: hunting and fishing"
      }, {
        "@Title": " hiking and camping",
        "@ID": "23",
        "@ParentID": "18",
        "@Narrative": "Activities: hiking and camping"
      }, {
        "@Title": " swims regularly",
        "@ID": "24",
        "@ParentID": "18",
        "@Narrative": "Activities: swims regularly"
      }]
    }, {
      "@Title": "Tobacco Use",
      "@ID": "27",
      "@ParentID": "1",
      "helpNavNode": [{
        "@Title": "Cigar, Cigarette, Pipe, Smokeless",
        "@ID": "30",
        "@ParentID": "27",
        "helpNavNode": {
          "@Title": "10/pk year",
          "@ID": "32",
          "@ParentID": "30",
          "@Narrative": "Tobacco Use:Cigar, Cigarette, Pipe, Smokeless:10/pk year"
        }
      }, {
        "@Title": "Quit Date",
        "@ID": "35",
        "@ParentID": "27",
        "@Narrative": "Tobacco Use:Quit Date"
      }, {
        "@Title": "Year Started",
        "@ID": "36",
        "@ParentID": "27",
        "@Narrative": "Tobacco Use:Year Started"
      }]
    }, {
      "@Title": "SocHx  Template",
      "@ID": "37",
      "@ParentID": "1",
      "helpNavNode": [{
        "@Title": " Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: ",
        "@ID": "41",
        "@ParentID": "37",
        "@Narrative": "SocHx  Template: Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: "
      }, {
        "@Title": " Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: ",
        "@ID": "42",
        "@ParentID": "37",
        "@Narrative": "SocHx  Template: Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: "
      }]
    }]
  }
}
var mapping = {
  '@Title': 'text',
  '@ID': 'id',
  '@ParentID': 'parent',
  '@Narrative': 'value'
}
var temp = JSON.stringify(data);
for (key in mapping) {
  temp = temp.replace(new RegExp(key, 'g'), mapping[key]);
}
data = JSON.parse(temp.replace(/@/g, ''));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: @T J this data = JSON.parse(temp.replace(/@/g, '')); line gives an error. error message is Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: "/" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.

Comment: @zeelong are you not running this in a javascript environment..? Because there is no such error in the demo in answer...

Comment: @T J when i ran this in chrome it given me the the error

Comment: @T J your code works really nicely in the demo but when i ran it in the <script> blocks on my view it gives me that error